# How to find the distance between two matrices

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices. I want to find the distance between points of two matrix. So I output a third matrix, that is distance between the two matrix.

For example distance between 200*3 and 3*1 output is 200*1 matrix

The distance formula I want to apply is

```
sqrt((x2 -x1)^2 -(y2-y1)^2)
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What you wrote is a statement.

Comment: you might want to refer [`pdist2`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)

Comment: @michael_0815 My question is 
A =200*3 matrix and B = 1*3 matrix or B' = 3*1 matrix 
How to find the distance between A and B, 

PS: distance formulae I want to apply is sqrt((x2 -x1)^2 -(y2-y1)^2 with this formulae I want to find the new matrix ? 

let me know If my question is not clear ?

Comment: Don't put your question in comments, edit your new material into your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 3; 4 4 4];
B = [1 2 3];
C = A - ones(size(A,1),1)*B;    % calculate differences
C = C.*C;       % square everything
C = sum(C');    % sum up the terms for each vector
distances = sqrt(C)
```